# Perl check array element exists in file

Tags: file, perl

I need to check whether the array element from `@lines` is exists in data file. From data file, corresonding element need to check is `problem`. If yes, print respective data items in the screen. Items are `problem`,`occaredtime`,`text`.

Script is below:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my @lines = qw/problem1 problem4/;
print Dumper \@lines;

while (<DATA>){
    my ($problem, $time, $text);

    my $line = $_;
    chomp($line);

    if( $line =~ /problem\s+:\s+(.*)/ ){
        $problem    =   $1; 
    }

    if( $line =~ /time\s+:\s+(.*)/ ){
        $time   =   $1; 
    }

    if( $line =~ /comment\s+:\s+(.*)/ ){
        $text   =   $1; 
    }

    if (grep { $_ eq $problem } @lines){
        print "Exists: $problem ** $time ** $text\n";
    }       
}

__DATA__
problem : problem1
occaredtime : 2020-03-17T06:28:18
comment : this is text for problem1

problem : problem2
occaredtime : 2020-03-17T05:00:00
comment : this is text for problem2

problem : problem3
occaredtime:2020-03-17T01:00:00
comment : this is text for problem3
```

But here its printing data like below instead of single line:

```
Exists: problem1 **  **
Exists: problem1 ** 2020-03-17T06:28:18 **
Exists: problem1 ** 2020-03-17T06:28:18 ** this is text for problem1
Exists: problem1 ** 2020-03-17T06:28:18 ** this is text for problem1
```

Could someone please let me know why its printing in this way.

EDIT:

I need to print only below line:

```
Exists: problem1 ** 2020-03-17T06:28:18 ** this is text for problem1
```

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 bugs.  Firstly, you need to declare the `$problem` variable outside the loop because you want to retain its value after each line; the same applies to the time variable.  Secondly, you should only test if the problem is desired when you are reading the `comment` line:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @lines = qw/problem1 problem4/;

my ($problem, $time, $text);
while (<DATA>){

    my $line = $_;
    chomp($line);

    if( $line =~ /problem\s+:\s+(.*)/ ){
        $problem    =   $1; 
    }

    if( $line =~ /time\s+:\s+(.*)/ ){
        $time   =   $1; 
    }

    if( $line =~ /comment\s+:\s+(.*)/ ){
        $text   =   $1; 
        if (grep { $_ eq $problem } @lines){
            print "Exists: $problem ** $time ** $text\n";
        }       
    }
}
```